# Wildcard Search in -Filter

Tags: powershell, filter

Want to have a better understanding of filter option like

This is yielding proper result

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'vss'"
```

How to have a wildcard search inside the filter without piping it to the where condition like :

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='v*'"

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='*v*'"

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='v'"

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name like 'v*'"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "name LIKE 'vss%'"
```

It uses WQL for the filtering (% is wildcard)

Which ends up being run as

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From win32_service Where name Like 'vss%'"
```

Comment: Thanks. The percentage is the wildcard. Lol sql stuff, i missed it. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE 'MsDtsServer%'"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).